# How to load a Java KeyStore certificate into a Tomcat server without using files

Tags: java, spring, ssl, tomcat, keystore

I have imported a certificate from Azure Key Vault and loaded it into a Java KeyStore object. I am supposed import this object programmatically into a Tomcat server, that is without using files. Is this doable, and if so how?

The certificate from Azure key vault was successfully loaded into the Java KeyStore object. However, I am not familiar with how to configure Tomcat via Java code. I tried to use ChatGPT as a starting point, and it suggested the following:

```
    import org.apache.catalina.Context;
    import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
    import org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig;
    import org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ConfigurableWebServerFactory;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    
    import java.security.KeyStore;
    
    @Configuration
    public class TomcatSslConfiguration {
    
        @Bean
        public ConfigurableWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
                @Override
                protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                    // Programmatically configure SSL
                    configureSsl(context);
                }
            };
            return factory;
        }
    
        private void configureSsl(Context context) {
            // Create and load your KeyStore programmatically
            KeyStore keyStore = loadKeyStore();
    
            // Create an SSLHostConfigCertificate
            SSLHostConfigCertificate sslHostConfigCertificate = new SSLHostConfigCertificate();
            sslHostConfigCertificate.setCertificateKeystore(keyStore);
    
            // Create an SSLHostConfig
            SSLHostConfig sslHostConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
            sslHostConfig.addCertificate(sslHostConfigCertificate);
    
            // Set the SSLHostConfig in the Tomcat context
            context.addSslHostConfig(sslHostConfig);
        }
    
        private KeyStore loadKeyStore() {
            // Implement your custom logic to load the KeyStore
            // For example, you can use KeyStore.getInstance("JKS") and load it from a custom     source
            // KeyStore keyStore = ...
    
            return keyStore;
        }
    }
```

Anyways, it seems like the `context.addSslHostConfig` does not exist. And I am not sure if this is a good starting point. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You need to write the loadKeyStore() part and add a saveKeyToStore() or similar. [Keystore api](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore) could help there

Comment: What do you mean ‘without using files’? Your certificate is in a file, and so is your private key.

Comment: @user207421 Why is that? Keys nor certificates need to be stored in files, and we don't even know if this is a trusted cert or a leaf cert of which the user has the private key at all.

Comment: Could you tell us what you want to achieve with the certificate instead of what you are trying to do with it? Because it might well be that we are staring at a huge XY-problem.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The private key is generated in a file. The CSR is generated in a file. The signed certificate is generated in a file. Yes they can be encoded into the program as data, but what exactly is the point? They all need to remain accessible, so that the certificate can be renewed for example. And if it's a trusted certificate there is no security aspect to it at all. It's a public document.

Comment: @user207421 Glad you can tell me all about that, it's not like I have any rep here on SO & SE w.r.t. cryptography. That these things are binary doesn't mean they are files, could well be that a trust cert is downloaded from the cloud, right? Trusted certs do need to be available and authentic, that's 2 out of 3 out of the CIA triangle if I'm not mistaken, we're only missing the C. Currently we just don't know much about the config.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I answered that way because I don't understand what you're talking about or why you are asking such strange questions, and making strange non-English statements like 'keys nor certificates need to be stored in files': is a 'neither' missing there? Perhaps you could explain.

Answer (score 0):

I also attempted in the past to use a custom ssl configuration, where I didn't want to specify the path and password as properties but just passing a keystore, or keymanager/trustmanager or even already initialized sslcontext. However it is not possible. See also my question regarding something similar to your question: [Configuring SSL programatically of a Spring Boot server with Tomcat is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77322685/configuring-ssl-programatically-of-a-spring-boot-server-with-tomcat-is-failing)

I opened a pull request on GitHub of Tomcat, see here: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/pull/673
Looking at the comment on the PR, it seems like they are discussing it internally whether to enable it.